# Get return codes from sql operations

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using sqlite library for C++ to work with database. I want to get return values from sqlite3_exec() function as used in below code.

For eg., if I execute a "DELETE from COMPANY where id=2;", I want to distinguish between the results of this query(it it deleted an existing row or it didn't or if the table exists or not).

All I am able to do using below code is execute the SQL statement. Is it possible to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlite3.h> 

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
   int i;
   fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", (const char*)data);
   for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int rc;
   char *sql;
   const char* data = "Callback function called";

   /* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }

   /* Create merged SQL statement */
   sql = "DELETE from COMPANY where ID=2; " \
         "SELECT * from COMPANY";

   /* Execute SQL statement */
   rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);
   if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Operation done successfully\n");
   }
   sqlite3_close(db);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the value of rc tell you what happened? https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html

Comment: @Marichyasana It gives rc=1 if it tries to delete from a table that doesn't exists and rc=0 otherwise. But still, I am not able to identify the cases if the key to be deleted existed or not. Please help.